# Binding Source Filter not working in DGV

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with the binding source on a DGV .  The message is "DataMember Property 'nodes' cannot be found on the dataSource " The column count is 14 after setting the table to the datasource.  The error occurs on the line   nodesDataGridView.DataSource = bsNodes. If I break before the error and then hover on the ds it does show that table nodes is in the datasource. I've used code similiar to this to setup other DGV's and I don't see any difference in this one.

if I remove these statements, I don't get the error but of course it is not filtered):

```
        nodesDataGridView.DataSource = bsNodes
        bsNodes.Filter = "company_number = " & Globals.customer_id
```

I should probably mention that I added company_number after the grid was completed and working.  It was setup for a single company code but now I'm having to add the requirement to support multiple companies in the database.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Vic

```
' Setup objects for loading the summary grid
Dim sqlNodes As String = "Select *From nodes order by display_sequence"
Dim comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlNodes, m_cn1)
Dim daNodes As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(comm)
Dim dsNodes As DataSet = New DataSet()
dim bsNodes As New BindingSource

    Try
        AddHandler ButtonSaveChanges.Click, AddressOf ButtonSaveChanges_Click
        dsNodes.Clear()
        daNodes.Fill(dsNodes, "nodes")
        m_cn1.Close()
        nodesDataGridView.DataSource = dsNodes
        nodesDataGridView.DataMember = "nodes"
        bsNodes.DataSource = dsNodes.Tables("nodes")
        Debug.Print("nodes column count is " & nodesDataGridView.ColumnCount)
        nodesDataGridView.DataSource = bsNodes
        bsNodes.Filter = "company_number = " & Globals.customer_id

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to load summary grid" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work - does anyone know why this is failing?  I am really stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to filter like this

```
bsNodes.Filter = "company_number = '" & Globals.customer_id.ToString() & "'"
```

EDIT:

```
    bsNodes.DataSource = dsNodes.Tables("nodes")
    nodesDataGridView.DataSource = bsNodes '<- you set dsNodes(Dataset) this should be the BindingSource not Dataset
    nodesDataGridView.DataMember = "nodes"
    Debug.Print("nodes column count is " & nodesDataGridView.ColumnCount)
    'nodesDataGridView.DataSource = bsNodes
    bsNodes.Filter = "company_number = '" & Globals.customer_id.ToString() & "'"
```

Comment: Spajce, thanks for the answer but the error occurs prior to setting the filter. Also, company_number is an int field.

Comment: i modified my answer.. i added `ToString()` so the integer will convert to string.

Comment: I'm getting the error "DataMember Property 'nodes' cannot be found on the dataSource " before I set the filter on the binding source.  Look at my original description of the problem.

Comment: ok try to check again.. you should set the `BindingSource` to `DataGridView.DataSource` not the `DataSet`

Comment: That was it ...   Thanks spajc I really appreciate your help in solving this!